# How to match text between as key-value pairs

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a RegExp that will evaluate a CSS code; to match a selector, display name and properties. I’m not too familiar with regular expressions, so I’ve this expression that can match a selector -if exists- and display name: `/(?'selector'\#|\.?)(?'display'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*)\s*(?=\{)(.*?)(?=\})/gm`.

I’ve managed to match selector and display group, what I can’t do is matching properties. For example in the following string, I want to have a group **inside** the match, that will return `background: red` and another group that will return `color: green`.

I can match the content between delimiters (`{` and `}`) with lookahead and lookbehind, but I couldn’t manage to create groups in my match to extract my properties.

I’m testing these on this string: `#id { background: red; color: green; }`

To be clear, my desired result on this string is:

1. Selector (working)
2. Name (working)
3. First property (in this case, this value should be `background: red`)
4. Second property (in this case, this value should be `color: green`)
5. Other properties if they exist

Comment: Where are the CSS rules? (in a `.css` file? in a style block in a page? inline on elements?) What is the goal of matching the rules? If you solve this and get all the parts you're trying to match, what are you going to do with them? Tagged as `javascript` — is the JS running in the page where the rules are?  
I ask all this because it may be more useful to manipulate the actual style _rules_ rather than the text that _defines_ the rules. Your JS can access [`document.styleSheet`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets) and read the rules from there.

Comment: I see this as an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) — you are (X) trying to do something with the styles and you've decided that (Y) using regex to parse them is the way to go; so you are asking about Y when there may be a better approach to solve X. This is why it's also good to mention your goal in the question.

Comment: Sorry if I couldnt’t make myself clear, I’m trying to compile CSS to AST outside browser environment (specifically Typescript). This is an internal function, I’ll load up the CSS, so it doesn’t matter where its origin is (stylesheet, inline etc.). Like I said, I need to match properties as groups in my expression, but I can’t find a way for it. Thanks.

Comment: Given this, that you're trying to build an AST, I would write a parser. The parser would use regexes within it, but wouldn't try to decompose the whole CSS rule from a single regex. A CSS rule can have multiple/unknown-number of property:value declarations and I think it is _far_ easier to parse those individually, the code would be more understandable than a complex regex, and easier to maintain/modify. I'll write an exampl answer of what I'm thinking if I can fit that in my schedule today — but it comes down to using String.split(/.../) with regexes to separate the main parts of a CSS rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than trying to decompose the whole CSS rule in a single complex regex, I would write a simple parser that *uses* simpler regexes.

A CSS rule consists of clearly defined separate parts:
A *selector*<sup>[1]</sup>, an open brace '{', some *declarations*, and a close brace '}'

```
<selector> '{'
    <declaration>';'*
'}'
```

A *declaration* is a *property*, a colon ':', the *value*, then a semi-colon ';'

Using these key characters `{:;}` we can use three *simple* regexes to split the rule into its parts.
The first regex looks a bit complicated at first glance because it accounts for optional whitespace, so uses `\s*` in several places:

```
/^\s*(?<selector>[^{]+)\s*{\s*(?<declarations>.+)\s*}/ms
```

but it's basically only looking for and separating the selector and some declarations that are enclosed in braces `{...}`
Note it uses multi-line search `m` and also uses the "dotAll" option `s` so it can match CSS rules as they are usually written, on multiple lines.

Once it's got those it uses simple string `.split`s to break down each declaration.  Declarations end in semi-colons so it will do a `.split(/\s*;\s*/)` resulting in an array of declarations. Each declaration is the `property:value` pair, so that will split on colon `:` and de-structure the resulting array: `[property, value] = declaration.split(/\s*:\s*/)`

I create a function using those steps which takes the CSS rule as a string and returns an object representing the selector and all of the declarations.

```js
const ruleA = '#id { background:red; color: green; }';
const ruleB = `#id {
    background: red;
    color:green;
}`;

let parsedRule = parseRule(ruleB);
console.log('parsedRule:', parsedRule);
  
function parseRule(rule) {
    const re_rule =
        /^\s*(?<selector>[^{]+)\s*{\s*(?<declarations>.+)\s*}/ms;
    const base = re_rule.exec(rule);
    const selector = base.groups.selector.trim();
    const declarations = base.groups.declarations.trim();

    const result = {
        'selector' : selector,
        'declarations' : []
    };

    declarations.split(/\s*;\s*/)
        .forEach(d => {
            [property, value] = d.split(/\s*:\s*/);
            //console.log('prop length:', property.length);
            //console.log(`property: '${property}'`);
            //console.log(`value:' '${value}'`);
            if (property?.trim().length > 0) {
                result.declarations.push({
                    "prop" : property,
                    "value" : value
                });
            }
        });

    return result;
}
```

[1] "a selector" could, of course, be multiple comma-separated selectors, and that could be handled, but I'm omitting it to keep this example simpler and, hopefully, clearer.